# Confusion regarding regular language

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

A regular language is a language that can be represented by a `regular expression`(or for which there exists a *DFA*), then why is language represented by  **0$^{+}$**   not regular?

I am asking this because for the following question the correct answer is **option 2**

Let L denote the languages generated by the grammar *S→0S0∣00*. 
Which of the following is TRUE?

1. L=0$^{+}$
2. L is regular but not 0$^{+}$
3. L is context free but not regular
4. L is not context free

Comment: Because $L$ it is regular and it is not $00^*$ but $00(00)^*$, so this refers to $L$ being a different language, not to deny that $0^+$ is regular?

Comment: @Evil My bad, english is not my native language.

Comment: Please give a reference for the problem you quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statement (2) is ambiguous. It could mean either
$$
L \text{ is regular but } L \text{ is not equal to } 0^+ \tag{1}
$$
Or it could mean,
$$
L \text{ is regular but } 0^+ \text{ is not regular} \tag{2}
$$
(1) is true and (2) is false.
The authors of the question intended it to mean (1).
But you thought that the meaning was (2), so you were confused.